# How to use a short local file reference in html

Tags: html

I can't make a specific file like: `file:///media/removable/USB%20Drive/Music/mp.3/sub_urban_cradles_official_music_video_4etlBXMByoK-gucZnSJ_.mp3`. into a simple universal file like simple.mp3. I want to be able to add my mp3s to the following code but can't because it's too specific:

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <audio src="audio.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
   <button id="myBtn">Play Audio</button>
   <script>  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
       document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
     }
     );
   </script>
 </body>
</html>

<!-- for some reason, it doesn't work here but the code is on:https://programminghead.com/how-to-play-audio-in-html-using-javascript/ -->
```

like how does: `<audio src="audio.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>` work? If I put audio.mp3 in a search engine it goes to a webpage and not the audio. but when I click the play button it plays audio. how? I would like to be able to make a link like that so my mp3s will work in place of audio.mp3.

Comment: What's a "simple universal file"?  The file name you provided (`sub_urban_cradles_official_music_video_4etlBXMByoK-gucZnSJ_.mp4`) doesn't sound like it's an MP3 audio file at all, it sounds like it's an MP4 **video** file.  Are you just asking how to convert the audio from that video file into an MP3?  Something else?  Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: oh my god im so stupid yes that is a video ill get the mp3 and simple universal file probably isnt a actual thing, just look at audio.mp3 its a simple file and it doesnt have all the extra stuff like: file:///media/removable/USB%20Drive/Music/mp.3/ (the stuff that tells the device where to put the file)

Comment: They're both files.  One is no more "simple" than the other.  The "stuff that tells the device where to put the file" is called the *file path*.  In the case of `src="file:///media/removable/USB%20Drive/Music/mp.3/sub_urban_cradles_official_music_video_4etlBXMByoK-gucZnSJ_.mp3"` the HTML is indicating that the audio file is in a specific file system path (which one really shouldn't ever need to use in a web page), whereas in the case of `src="audio.mp3"` the HTML is indicating that the audio file would be found in the same path as the page being viewed.  It's a "relative path".

Comment: but how do I make it so it doesn't need the file path, when i remove it it just doesn't work at all.

Comment: By including the file in the same folder (or hosted URL structure) as the page.  You are encouraged to start with some introductory tutorials on making HTML web pages.  Linking to other pages, scripts, CSS files, images, and other such resources (like an audio or video file) is introductory functionality.  You won't solve this by begging people not to delete your questions.  You will solve this by learning and understanding HTML and web pages in general.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294776/208273).  It is exactly for asking how to do things.  You are, however, correct that extended conversations are discouraged.

Comment: Just use glitch.com. thanks for the help guys and I hope this becomes a post thar is helpful for other people out there that don't know as much about code as alot of people here do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To play a specific file, then you need a specific unique reference to that file! If you are interested in playing multiple files, or controlling a playlist, then you might be interested in a sample like this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5164334/Create-Music-Playlist-with-HTML5-and-JavaScript?msclkid=029eb55ec0f911eca54f7b314e3fd12c
>
> If you copy your audio file into the same folder as your html file, then you can reference that file by it's name only, and not include the full file path, if you rename that file to `audio.mp3` then it would match the example.

That `audio.mp3` reference is a route reference to the hosted site, it may not represent a specific file, it might be a registered route that the server is programmed to resolve the actual file to play. So if you wanted many files to be *served* through a common route you would need some code that *handles* that route and knows how to select the actual file that you want to serve.

To reference your file then we expect to see html like this:

```
<audio src="file:///media/removable/USB%20Drive/Music/mp.3/sub_urban_cradles_official_music_video_4etlBXMByoK-gucZnSJ_.mp3" id="myAudio" />
```

In the specific case of https://programminghead.com/how-to-play-audio-in-html-using-javascript the example html that does not include the full path to the audio file does not actually work, the working script actually references this full path:

```
<audio src="https://programminghead.com/audio/audio.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
```

Notice that this is in fact a *Fully Qualified URL*. If the file was hosted at the route of the site then it would be possible to use a relative link like

```
 <audio src="audio.mp3" id="myAudio"></audio>
```

But that would be translated by the browser into

```
https://programminghead.com/audio.mp3
```

See how the browser has injected the current *folder* URL to the page as the *prefix* for the `audio.mp3`. That is the assumed behaviour when the link is not fully defined. But there is no file at that location to play.

- Be careful when interpreting online code examples that are executable, especially if they reference external files. They are often simplified or contain modifications or artifcats that allow the code to run within the page that you are viewing them.

Understand first that file references and how they are resolved is common to all types of files and links in html, the `<audio src=""/>` behaves the same way as `<img src=""/>` or even `<a href=""></a>` in terms of how the browser resolves the actual file reference.

Comment: but if you go to https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default_default and past the code it will work too

Comment: It only works if you paste in the full file path to the audio file,  `<audio src="audio.mp3" id="myAudio">` doesn't work in the W3Schools try it now editor because that file doesn't exist. You can however use `<audio src="horse.mp3" id="myAudio">` because they deliberately host that file for their audio demos: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I just edited my post a bit, see if that helps you, the code project article is long to read but goes into more detail about file references and how to manage multiple files which might be what you are looking for. Normally we build an interface where the user can select the file they want, otherwise we would hardcode it to something very specific.

Comment: I have just read it all and I believe it will help me with the onclick playback audio. I will not know for sure though until I get on my computer, who knows, maybe that site will be blocked on th computer. But thanks a bunch for you help. 

Comment: Yes this helped  turns out glitch.com has a asset uploader that turns files into links